# Return ENUM - Cannot return null for non-nullable field

Tags: apollo, apollo-server, prisma, graphql-codegen

I am using apollo-server-lambda, Prisma ORM and graphql-codegen.

I have a query (`getBookById`) that returns a `Book`. `Book` contains an enum called `BookStatus`. I want to be able to return in ENUM in the playground but I get the error:

> Cannot return null for non-nullable field Book.bookStatus.

**BookStatus - TypeDef**

```
enum BookStatus {
  OPEN
  DRAFT
  CLOSED
}
```

**Book - TypeDef**

```
type Book {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  bookStatus: BookStatus!
}
```

**getBookById - TypeDef**

```
type Query {
  getBookById(getBookByIdInput: GetBookByIdInput): Book
}
```

[image: PLAYGROUND ERROR]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

The issue was that I was using Prisma as ORM.
When I was getting a new book, I was writing the code:

```
  const foundBook = await prisma.book.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: bookId
    }
  });
```

The issue is that the book was created using this code:

```
  const newBook = await prisma.book.create({
    data: {
      user_id: userId,
      title: title,
      author: author,
      publication_year: publicationYear,
      isbn: isbn,
      photos: photos,
      book_condition: bookCondition,
      exchange_yype: exchangeType,
      book_status: bookStatus,
    },
  });
      
  return newBook;

};
```

The mix of snake_case and camelCase created the issue.
Once everything was camelCase, the problem got solved.